# Chi square goodness of fit for random numbers generated

Tags: r, random, statistics, simulation

I have used Inverse CDF method to generate 1000 samples from **an exponential** and **a Cauchy** random variable.

Now to verify whether these belong to their relevant distributions, I have to perform Chi-Squared Test for Goodness of fit.

I have tried two approaches (as below) -

1. Chisq.test(y) #which has 1000 samples from supposed exponential distribution

   ```
   chisq.test(z) #cauchy
   ```

I am getting the following error:

> data: y
>   X-squared = 234.0518, df = 999, p-value = 1

```
 Warning message:
 In chisq.test(y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
  chisq.test(z)
 Error in chisq.test(z) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

2. I downloaded the **vcd** library to use **goodfit()**
   and typed:

   ```
       t1 <- goodfit(y,type= "exponential",method= "MinChiSq")
       summary(t1)
   ```

In this case, the error message:

```
   Error: could not find function "goodfit"
```

---

can somebody please guide on how to implement the Chi-Squared GOF test properly?

Note: The samples are not from normal distribution (exponential and cauchy respectively)
I am trying to understand if it is possible to get the observed and expected data instead with no luck so far.

**edit** - I did type in *library(vcd)* before writing the rest of the code. Apologies to have assumed it was obvious.

Comment: Usually for chi squared test you need "expected frequency" which might mean you should bin your data into bins of appropriate width (maybe 10 per bin). Then you have to compare "observed" and "expected" - in other words you need to give the probability `p` as another factor in the `chisq` function. See http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/goodness.html for simple example.

Comment: Did you ever actually load the package?  Just downloading using install.packages doesn't load the package.  You'll need to use `library(vcd)` to load it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chisq.test(...)` function is designed primarily for use with counts, so it expects its arguments to be either countable (using `table(...)` for example), or to be counts already. It basically creates a contingency table for `x` and `y` (the first two arguments) and then uses the chisq test to determine if they are from the same distribution.

You are probably better off using the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, which is designed for problems like yours. The K-S test compares the ecdf of the sample to the cdf of the test distribution and tests the null hypothesis that they are the same.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rexp(1000),
                 z = rcauchy(1000, 100, 100))

ks.test(df$y,"pexp")
# One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
# data:  df$y
# D = 0.0387, p-value = 0.1001
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(df$z,"pcauchy",100,100)    
#  One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  df$z
# D = 0.0296, p-value = 0.3455
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Note that in this case, the K-S test predicts a 90% chance that your sample `df$y` did *not* come from an exponential distribution, even though it clearly did.

You can use `chisq.test(...)` by artificially binning your data and then comparing the counts in each bin to what would be expected from your test distribution (using `p=...`), but this is convoluted and the answer you get depends on the number of bins.

```
breaks <- c(seq(0,10,by=1))
O <- table(cut(df$y,breaks=breaks))
p <- diff(pexp(breaks))
chisq.test(O,p=p, rescale.p=T)
#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  O
# X-squared = 7.9911, df = 9, p-value = 0.535
```

In this case the chisq test predicts a 47% chance that your sample did *not* come from an exponential distribution.

Finally, even though they are qualitative, I find Q-Q plots to be very useful. These plot quantiles of your sample against quantiles of the test distribution. If the sample is drawn from the test distribution, the Q-Q plot should fall close to the line `y=x`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(qexp(seq(0,1,0.01)),quantile(df$y,seq(0,1,0.01)),
     main="Q-Q Plot",ylab="df$Y", xlab="Exponential",
     xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0,5))
plot(qcauchy(seq(0,.99,0.01),100,100),quantile(df$z,seq(0,.99,0.01)),
     main="Q-Q Plot",ylab="df$Z",xlab="Cauchy",
     xlim=c(-1000,1000),ylim=c(-1000,1000))
```

[image]

Looking at the Q-Q plots gives me much more confidence in asserting that `df$y` and `df$z` are drawn, respectively, from the Exponential and Cauchy distributions than either the K-S or ChiSq tests, even though I can't put a number on it.

Comment: +1. K-S test will tend to fail to reach significance for larger sample sizes, where visual methods are more appropriate. e.g. `set.seed(6); 
y = rexp(10); ks.test(y, "pexp")`

Comment: Very helpful. Can I hear your opinion about breaks calculation using following method: `breaks <- hist(df$y,breaks="Sturges",plot=FALSE)$breaks`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Simulation

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y = rexp(1000),
                 z = rcauchy(1000, 100, 100)
                 )

#This seems to be different, probably because of how you are simulating the data
chisq.test(df$y)

#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  df$y
# X-squared = 978.485, df = 999, p-value = 0.6726
#
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(df$y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

**3 details:**

```
1) you need to load the package. library(vcd)
2) There is no "exponential" type of distribution in the goodfit function
3) the method is MinChisq, Not MinChiSq
```

.

```
library(vcd)
t1 <- goodfit(df$y, type= "binomial", method= "MinChisq")
summary(t1)

#        Goodness-of-fit test for binomial distribution
#    
#                 X^2 df     P(> X^2)
#    Pearson 31.00952  6 2.524337e-05
#    Warning message:
#    In summary.goodfit(t1) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: I did follow 1) and 3) but yeah "exponential " doesn't exist . How does one go about it then ? Any pointers ? Or is binning only way to go about it ?

Comment: @Raak If you are working with factor variables (categorical) the idea behind the chisq.test is to test the independence or relation between these two (or more) categorical variables. As you are working with numeric data, binning doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Raaj read the ?chisq.test, the first paragraph after details. "If x is a matrix with one row or column, or if x is a vector and y is not given, then a goodness-of-fit test is performed (x is treated as a one-dimensional contingency table). The entries of x must be non-negative integers. In this case, the hypothesis tested is whether the population probabilities equal those in p, or are all equal if p is not given."

Comment: @Raaj This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408357/chi-squared-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Okay so per that link, I'm thinking I should use set.seed and generate 1000 samples from the "rexp", store it in a vector as expected values, and then compare them against my inverse CDF values as observed values.

Also, my problem of "goodfit not found" remains. Maybe i should google more (so far all i have come across is wrong function calls/ no calls).

Comment: `set.seed()` is to reproduce your analysis in the future. It's not the simulation itself. You do this with `rexp` or `rcauchy`. The rcauchy test doesn't work because of the negative values, "The entries of x must be non-negative integers".